# Test own cmdlets

Tags: .net, powershell

Is there any common practice for testing cmdlets written in C#?
I'm interested in something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var cmdlet = new MyCmdlet();
    cmdlet.Property1 = "something 1";
    cmdlet.Property2 = "something 2";

    var actualOutput = Execute(cmdlet);

    AssertCmdLetOut(expectedOutput, actualOutput);  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very elegant. But still more than nothing: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/cazzu/archive/2006/10/26/PowerShellUnitTestCmdlet.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this Cmdlet:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Lorem")]
public class LoremCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteObject ("Lorem Ipsum");
    }
}
```

A sample xunit test might be:

```
public class LoremCmdletTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Should_Return_a_Canoncial_String()
    {
        // arrange
        LoremCmdlet cmdlet = new LoremCmdlet();
        string actual = null;

        // act
        IEnumerator result = cmdlet.Invoke().GetEnumerator();
        result.MoveNext();
        actual = result.Current.ToString();

        // assert
        Assert.Equal("Lorem Ipsum", actual);
    }

}
```